# How to use regex with the same prefix but different suffix?

Tags: r, regex, string

Let's say that My data has the following structure:

```
Data<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(17955, 17955, 17954, 17954, 
17953), class = "Date"), name = c("QLD to SA", "QLD.NSW to SA.NSW", 
"QLD to SA", "QLD.NSW to SA.NSW", "QLD to SA"), value = c(-2.33611657245688, 
-1.48768446629906, -2.36699803453011, -1.46423011205677, -2.32284554692339
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to create a new column called Group. This column depends on the regular expressions in my column `name`. What I want is an ouput like this:

```
 Date       name              value Group
2019-02-28 QLD to SA         -2.34 QLD  
2019-02-28 QLD.NSW to SA.NSW -1.49 QLD-NSW  
2019-02-27 QLD to SA         -2.37 QLD  
2019-02-27 QLD.NSW to SA.NSW -1.46 QLD-NSW  
2019-02-26 QLD to SA         -2.32 QLD
```

I think that something like this could function:

```
Data%>%mutate(Group=case_when(
    str_detect(name, regex("QLD", ignore_case=TRUE)) ~ "QLD",
    str_detect(name, regex("^QLD.NSW", ignore_case=TRUE)) ~ "QLD-NSW",
                         T ~ "number"))
```

It fails because the column group recognize only the first case `QLD` and stop it for the second `QLD-NSW`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to swap the two lines of code starting with `str_detect`.

Please find below a reprex.

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(tidyverse)

Data%>%mutate(Group=case_when(
  str_detect(name, regex("^QLD\\.NSW", ignore_case=TRUE)) ~ "QLD-NSW",
  str_detect(name, regex("QLD", ignore_case=TRUE)) ~ "QLD",
  T ~ "number"))
```

- Output

```r
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   Date       name              value Group  
#>   <date>     <chr>             <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1 2019-02-28 QLD to SA         -2.34 QLD    
#> 2 2019-02-28 QLD.NSW to SA.NSW -1.49 QLD-NSW
#> 3 2019-02-27 QLD to SA         -2.37 QLD    
#> 4 2019-02-27 QLD.NSW to SA.NSW -1.46 QLD-NSW
#> 5 2019-02-26 QLD to SA         -2.32 QLD
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>